# Script to find intrinsic size of HTML image

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to find the intrinsic size of an image in a HTML document from Javascript?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Very old question, but this is where I ended up when I searched.
These days (since IE9) there are `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` properties:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight

I think these give me what I want.

Answer (score 5):

Create an Image element in your script and set the `src` attribute to the same URL as the image you want to measure. Then you can read the `width` and `height` attributes.

For reliable results you'll want to ensure that the image is loaded, as in this complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    img { width: 100% }
</style>
<img id="my_image_element" src="rustacean.jpeg">
<script>
    var url = my_image_element.src;
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
        console.log("Intrinsic size: "+ img.width +"x"+ img.height);
    };
    img.src = url;
</script>
```

[credit](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/573081-intrinsic-size-image)

Comment: @Lal: This is explicitly encouraged by the founder: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Yes it is ok..but..see the time when both are posted..exactly the same..@AlexK.

Comment: it is not working for my case where I set the source of the image dynamically on runtime